# dataset versus rowset in SQL cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to do a compare and then update a value if there is a difference. The query will update every row in the person table if the subquery contains any rows. Since there is on connection between UPDATE's person and the subquery, that means that all rows will be updated. I need it to only update the rows that are actually different. Any advice would be welcome.

```
with cte as (
     select [ID_person],[NM_firstname] from dbo.person where load_date='load1'
     except
     select [ID_person],[NM_firstname] from dbo.person where load_date='load2'
)
update cte
set Marking_Field='10'
```

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking, but have you looked at using MERGE instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Actually different from what? Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.  I added the sql-server tag, because you appear to be using SQL Server